# How to construct a URI with username password for mongo C driver.

Tags: c, mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I am using mongo 3.0.8. I have an authenticated user admin with password admin. I am able to connect to the mongo shell as follows.

mongo admin -u amdin -p amdin

However, i tried to connect to using the following C code. This gives me an error

> WARNING:       client: Failed to connect to: ipv4 127.0.0.1:27017,
>   error: 111, Connection refused

```
char URI[256];
snprintf(URI,256,"mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin");
mongoc_client_t *client = mongoc_client_new(URI);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `error: 111, Connection refused` is a networking error.
Your URI expecting to find the server listening on port 27017 of the same machine (127.0.0.1).  Possible issues:

- Server not running
- Server not on that port
- Server is bound to the "real ip address" of the machine.
- There is local firewall (e.g. iptables) blocking access
- Maybe an SELinux problem?

If this is a Linux box, these commands might help diagnose:

```
netstat -an -A inet | grep LISTEN
/sbin/iptables -L
```